# How to change token label without re-initializing it?

Tags: java, pkcs#11, iaik-jce

I'm aware of `initToken(char[] pin, java.lang.String label)` from the [IAIK docs](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_wrapper/current/iaik/pkcs/pkcs11/Token.html#initToken(char[],%20java.lang.String)). But the function will reset the token and any data in the token would be lost. I just want to change the token label without losing token's content. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard function in PKCS#11 to change the token label. Thus, it seems that the only way to change the label is re-initialization using `C_initToken`.